# Description Resource Path Location Type cannot open output file character.exe: Permission denied character C/C++ Problem

Tags: c

please help me how can solve Path   Location problem    "Type cannot open output file character.exe: Permission denied"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;

       c = getchar( );
       setbuf(stdout,NULL);
       printf( "enter a character:");
       scanf("%c",&c);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

This error typically happens on windows systems if you attempt to modify either a file that another app has open or an executable which is currently running.

You most likely left a copy of your program running when trying to compile a new version, so make sure there are no running instances before recompiling.

Comment: @ASNAVA Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.